# How can I return variants of an ActiveStorage image over GraphQL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, rails-activestorage

### Summary

For a given GraphQL query against a Ruby on Rails 7 endpoint:

```
query {
    posts(limit: 1) {
        id
        caption
        image {
            web # <- this is a variant name
            thumb # <- another variant name
        }
    }
}
```

I want a response that looks like this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "8d59b87c-c33b-4c29-b18f-a4d6aa2abf45",
                "caption": "Nam ad incidunt. Nisi sequi quibusdam. Nihil quis veritatis. Beatae consequatur excepturi. Et at sapiente. Delectus deleniti unde. Id a quo. Qui aut quod. Est qui quo. Dolores beatae facilis. Sed error vero. Est est at. Alias aut sit. Consequuntur consequ."
                "image": {
                    "web": "some-url-here",
                    "thumb": "another-url-here"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Where the `object` has an `image` property with multiple `variants` defined.

### Details

I'm working on a specific GraphQL query endpoint using Rails 7, the graphql-rails, and my intermediate knowledge of Ruby, but I've happened upon a stumbling block.

I have a project that accepts user uploads of photos, which then receive multiple modifications in the form of ActiveStorage variants. Each post a user makes includes one (and only one) attached image to be processed. After upload, a background job generates 5 different variants based on some model-specified dimensions.

For the sake of simplicity, here's the relevant part of the `Post` model:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :web, resize_to_fill: [1200, 1200, { crop: :centre }]
    attachable.variant :opengraph, resize_to_fill: [1200, 630, { crop: :attention }]
    attachable.variant :twitter, resize_to_fill: [1024, 512, { crop: :attention }]
    attachable.variant :mobile, resize_to_fill: [600, 600, { crop: :centre }]
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_fill: [100, 100, { crop: :centre }]
  end

...
```

The `Post` type for GraphQL is set to return a field named `image` of type `VariantType`, which I've included below in my current, inelegant version:

```rb
module Types
  class VariantType < Types::BaseObject
    field :web, String, null: false
    field :opengraph, String, null: false
    field :twitter, String, null: false
    field :mobile, String, null: false
    field :thumb, String, null: false
  end

  def web
    url_for(:web)
  end

  def opengraph
    url_for(:opengraph)
  end

  def twitter
    url_for(:twitter)
  end

  def mobile
    url_for(:mobile)
  end

  def thumb
    url_for(:thumb)
  end

  ... (method definition for url_for removed for clarity)
end
```

When I attempted to query the endpoint, instead of the JSON response above, I got the below error:

```
Failed to implement Variant.web, tried:
     
  - `Types::VariantType#web`, which did not exist
  - `ActiveStorage::Attached::One#web`, which did not exist
  - Looking up hash key `:web` or `"web"` on `<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x000000012511c5f8>`, but it wasn't a Hash
     
To implement this field, define one of the methods above (and check for typos)
```

### Update 1

The `url_for` method is defined as:

```rb
  def url_for(variant) # rubocop:disable Metrics/MethodLength
    img = object.image.variant(variant)

    # Add protocol if CDN_HOST doesn't have it
    cdn_host = ENV.fetch('CDN_HOST', nil)
    cdn_host = "https://#{cdn_host}" unless cdn_host.nil? || cdn_host.start_with?('http')
    if cdn_host.nil?
      blob_type = if img.is_a?(ActiveStorage::Variant) || img.is_a?(ActiveStorage::VariantWithRecord)
                    :rails_representation
                  else
                    :rails_blob
                  end

      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.route_for(blob_type, img, only_path: true)
    else
      File.join(cdn_host, img.key) # Returns CDN path for blob
    end
```

It's a hack, I know, in lieu of a better approach to having my asset URLs appear as `https://cdn.example.com/asset.jpg` instead of the ugly ActiveStorage proxy URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this issue would be to use the variant method provided by ActiveStorage to retrieve the variant you want. You can pass the variant name as a symbol to the variant method, like this:

```
def web
  object.image.variant(:web).service_url
end

def opengraph
  object.image.variant(:opengraph).service_url
end

def twitter
  object.image.variant(:twitter).service_url
end

def mobile
  object.image.variant(:mobile).service_url
end

def thumb
  object.image.variant(:thumb).service_url
end
```

This will retrieve the variant you want and return its URL using the service_url method.

Alternatively, you could define your VariantType like this:

```
module Types
  class VariantType < Types::BaseObject
    field :web, String, null: false, method: :web_url
    field :opengraph, String, null: false, method: :opengraph_url
    field :twitter, String, null: false, method: :twitter_url
    field :mobile, String, null: false, method: :mobile_url
    field :thumb, String, null: false, method: :thumb_url

    def web_url
      object.image.variant(:web).service_url
    end

    def opengraph_url
      object.image.variant(:opengraph).service_url
    end

    def twitter_url
      object.image.variant(:twitter).service_url
    end

    def mobile_url
      object.image.variant(:mobile).service_url
    end

    def thumb_url
      object.image.variant(:thumb).service_url
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you can define your fields with the method option, which allows you to specify a method to be called to resolve the field's value.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've edited the question to include the method definition for `url_for`, because it may be relevant in adding context to your answer (and why I can't use `service_url`).

The problem I have is that I need to replace the ActiveStorage-sourced domain with a CDN one configured via env var. How would that work with your approach?

(And if my approach to replacing the URL with the CDN version is bad, I'm happy to take feedback on it too)

Comment: And if you just use gsub after generate the url with service_url/url_for? for example: variant.service_url.gsub("active_storate_sourced_domain", ENV["CDN_DOMAIN"]) ?

Comment: The issue with that approach is that Rails generates asset URLs with non-root paths like `/rails/redirect/...` or `/rails/proxy/...`, which break when the domain is replaced with another.

I very much want to avoid sending traffic destined for the CDN through Rails.

Comment: This link captures the issue well: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/putting-a-cdn-in-front-of-activestorage/76948

Comment: Turns out I had the methods defined _outside_ the class itself, hence the error about no `VariantType.web` method found.

With the updated class below (I've also replaced `object.image` with just `object`, since `object` is already an instance of `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` in my case), the code works as expected.

Thank you for the help in debugging this!